# MongoDB Aggregation response format to unique key in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting response from mongoDB aggregation query which is grouped data and select fields dynamically which is on "projectionObj" object:

Here is my mongodb **aggregation query**:

```
   let projectionObj = {
          "date": 1,
          "height": 1,
          "bmi": 1,
          "level": 1,
    }

   UpdateForm.aggregate([
            { $match: {
                    "id": id,
                    "date": {
                        "$gte": startdate,
                        "$lte": enddate,
                    }}},
            { $group: {
                    _id: {
                        year: { $year: "$date" },
                        month: { $month: "$date" },
                        day: { $dayOfMonth: "$date" },
                    },
                    items: {
                        $push: '$$ROOT',
                    }}},
            {$project: {
                    "_id": 0,
                    "items": projectionObj
                }},
        ])
```

And below is **aggregation result**:

```
[
 {
  items: [{
    date: "2022-03-11",
    height: '1',
    bmi: '1',
    level: '1'
   },
   {
    date: "2022-03-11",
    height: '2',
    bmi: '2',
    level: '2'
   }]
},
{
  items: [{
    date: "2022-03-08",
    height: '3',
    bmi: '3',
    level: '3'
    }]
  }
]
```

I want to format aggregation result to desire able format which is given below

```
 {
   categories: ["2022-03-11", "2022-03-11", "2022-03-08"],
   series: [
          {name: "height", data: [1,2,3]},
          {name: "bmi", data: [1,2,3]},
          {name: "level", data: [1,2,3]},
     ]
 }
```

Comment: If you want them this way why are you grouping them?

Comment: Hello, i wanna plot this desire format to bar chat thats why am grouping them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first I ran `flatMap` on the array and got an array of individual items. then ran `reduce` to group the `series` based on names and to add dates to `categories`.
But now series is an object. to convert it to an array as you need I overrode `series` in the final result to take the array of grouped values using `Object.values`

```js
let a = [
 {
  items: [{
    date: "2022-03-11",
    height: '1',
    bmi: '1',
    level: '1'
   },
   {
    date: "2022-03-11",
    height: '2',
    bmi: '2',
    level: '2'
   }]
},
{
  items: [{
    date: "2022-03-08",
    height: '3',
    bmi: '3',
    level: '3'
    }]
  }
]

let res = a.flatMap(el => el.items).reduce((acc,{date,...curr})=>{
    acc.categories.push(date)
  Object.entries(curr).forEach(([k,v])=>{
    if(!acc.series[k])acc.series[k]={name:k,data:[]}
    acc.series[k].data.push(parseInt(v))
  })
  return acc;
},{categories:[],series:{}})

res = {...res,series:Object.values(res.series)}
console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can you please sort this by date.

Comment: sort is not difficult . which order to sort

Comment: `res = {...res,series:Object.values(res.series),categories:res.categories.sort((a,b)=> new Date(a)-new Date(b))}` for ascending. `res = {...res,series:Object.values(res.series),categories:res.categories.sort((a,b)=> new Date(b)-new Date(a))}`  for descending

Comment: thanks for your response but I want to sort all data with date wise not just categories... right now just categories array is sorting not data array in series.

Comment: then you can the sort step just after the flatmap like `a.flatMap(el => el.items).sort((a,b)=> new Date(a.date)-new Date(b.date)).reduce((acc....` and in the final answer just like `res = {...res,series:Object.values(res.series)}` without sort there

Comment: Working, thanks God blessed you :)